# What is wrong with my 301 htaccess modrewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snsd.html [R=301]
```

I want all indexed pages in google to be 301 directed to a page called snsd.html

However, i keep getting a redirect loop error.

I think i need to put a condition, if page is not snsd.html then do the 301 redirect. how do i do this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/snsd.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snsd.html [R=301]
```

I took the example off http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond